# How to check, if user commented before, on comment_post action?

Tags: comments, actions

I want check, if user commented post, in comment_post action. So i make this:

```
function checkUserComment( $comment_ID ) {

    $comment = get_comment( $comment_ID );
    $postID = $comment->comment_post_ID;
    $authorID = $comment->user_id;

    // If user commented this post already, don't update post meta.
    if( get_comments( array( 'post_id' => $postID, 'user_id' => $authorID ) ) )
        return;

    update_post_meta($postID, 'testMeta', 'testValue');

}

add_action( 'comment_post', 'checkUserComment', 10, 2 );
```

It must doesn't update post_meta if user comments first time. But it updates post_meta anyway.

Comment: To narrow the problem you have to check each variable values, e.g., by echoing it.

Comment: I checked all variables and print all them. Also tried `is_array()` and `!empty()` but same. I wonder, when action check it? After comment submisson or before?

Comment: And what is the problem exactly? You say it doesn’t work. How?

Comment: Updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/comment_post):

comment_post is an action triggered immediately after a comment is inserted into the database.

Instead, I think what you want to try is to hook into [preprocess_comment](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/preprocess_comment) and not comment_post.